# Aloe vera - How can I straighten/repot?

Tags: indoors, pruning, repotting, aloe

I've had my *Aloe vera* for over 10 years, and since I repotted it into a much bigger pot last summer it has grown uncontrollably. It's now way too tall and top-heavy and bends in several directions, but the top leaves look healthy and beautiful. How can I trim it to repot it, or is it too far gone to save? I do have several of its babies but I'm still a bit attached to this one...

[image: Aloe vera plant]

Comment: it is a lovely plant up top!  :)  do you want the plant to grow or be mostly stable?  repotting into a less nutrient laden mix can slow it down some (a bit less water and fertilizer).  you can take the babies and keep them in the same mix and conditions as you have been so they will grow more strongly so they can be used for juice.  no matter what though these plants can get leggy and need repotting from time to time.  glad you kept it alive this long.  :)

Comment: Thank you!!! I think I'd just like this one to be more stable, how would I go about repotting it safely at this point?

Comment: how long is the bottom part including the part still in the pot?  there are several ways of getting it repotted and preserving the top, but there are risks too.  since you have babies you won't lose the entire plant.  i would first get the babies in their own pot(s) and growing.

Comment: I'll definitely get the babies out first, but the big one is easily a foot and a half/two feet from the healthy top part to the soil, and probably another foot or so in the pot. if only I'd realized sooner I'm sure this would be a lot easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the pups growing in a different pot.

After you see signs the pups are actively growing then you can cut off the top and reroot it in new cacti potting soil.  I think 20cm or more of stem below the top leaves that you like should be enough, but if your new pot is deeper you can keep more of the stem.  It won't hurt it to have that buried and gradually rotting away while it reroots.  I would avoid direct sunlight or extreme heat until you see it growing.

If you want to give it a bit more insurance of rerooting you can find some rooting hormone to use.

Keep the new potting soil moist (not soggy just damp) until you see new growth and then gradually change over to what you were doing before but only a bit less since you don't want it to grow as strongly as before.